# i'm trying to return link of the first youtube video in search results using python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, youtube, href

i've tried all the possible ways i could think of. I don't want to use Selenium for this, however my code which used Selenium worked, but i can't get it to work with BeautifulSoup.

I also tried using youtube_dl in the following code:

```py
def get_addr(query):
    file = open('filename.txt', 'w')
    file.truncate(0)
    file.close()

    a = os.system(f"youtube-dl --get-url 'ytsearch:{query.replace(' ','+')}'> filename.txt")

    with open('filename.txt', 'r') as file:
        output = file.read(100)
    return output
```

the SELENIUM code that did work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from time import sleep

DOWN_PATH = r"C:\Users\91880\Music"

driver= webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

song_list = []
for song in song_list:
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={}'.format(song.replace(' ','+')))
    s = driver.find_element_by_id('video-title')
    print(s.text, s.get_attribute("href"), '', sep='\n')
```

Comment: You'd be better off using the youtube api than trying to parse the website

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but it can help you get you started.
When requesting youtube it requires you to press accept cookies, so we have to set a cookie to the request that says we already have accepted the cookies. Then you have to request it after the javascript executed or else the videos wont exist

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def findYT(search):
    search_param = {'search_query': search}
    search_result = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/results', params=search_param, cookies={'CONSENT': 'YES+42'}).text
    # Just writes to a temp file so you can inspect the code 
    with open("tmp.txt", "w") as f:
        f.write(search_result)
        f.close()

   
    #link = "https://www.youtube.com" + videos[0]["href"]

findYT("test")
```

If you look closely at the tmp.txt produced by the code, you will see that there is some json inside a script tag. You can find it by searching "watch?". There you will find all video links from the search param. Now you just gotta find a way to grab that json and get the right url.